# Usar correctamente las etiquetas de IDE's

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Esto es algo que quería publicar desde hace algún tiempo pero no había podido.

Se ha hecho habitual el uso de las etiquetas de ide, por ejemplo [android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio), [visual-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), etc. en preguntas que no tienen que ver nada.

Por ejemplo:

**Como hacer un factorial en java**

Etiquetado [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)

Cuando esta pregunta no tiene que ver nada con eclipse

¿Qué preguntas se deberían aceptar como preguntas con etiqueta ide?

Comment: Si pudiera votar 1000 veces por esta pregunta, lo haría. La cantidad de preguntas etiquetadas sólo con [tag:android-studio] y que luego son "¿Por qué recibo esta excepción en mi código?" es exagerada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro aun hasta hoy, casi un año despues se observa ese mismo problema, pienso que deberia haber un formulario para que los usuarios añadan las etiquetas correctas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Los no

**Como puedo pasar de una actividad a otra actividad en android studio**

Nada que ver con [android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio), solo necesita ser etiquetada como [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), incluso editar la pregunta y dejar solo *en android* seria suficiente

**Scanner no me lee correctamente números en eclipse**

Nada que ver con [eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) es [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) puro y duro

**Como separar una cadena de texto por coma en visual studio**

A mi aun me enoja mucho que le preguntas a una persona en que lenguaje esta desarrollando y responda visual studio, pongas tu cara de QUE?! Y continúe con- ahh Visual studio 2013.

¿Que hacer? preguntar por el lenguaje (si es que no se especifica en la pregunta ) y solo etiquetarla con el lenguaje no con [visual-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio))

**NullPointerException en eclipse**

*Tengo este código XYZ*

Respuesta:

*Te falta inicializar X*

Nada que ver con el IDE, problema totalmente del lenguaje de programación

**Función recursiva en Pyhon  tira el programa**

[python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)[pycharm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm)

Quitar [pycharm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm) parece ser solo un problema del lenguaje y su uso.

**Mi programa en falla en DevC++**

*El cuerpo muestra código con errores de uso del lenguaje C*

Quitar [devc++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devc%2b%2b) y dejar solo la etiqueta [c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

**tengo problemas tildes y ñ en android al consumir jsonParser?** [Ejemplo real](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/40567/2027)

Nada que ver con android-studio

**Subir imagen a mi Amazon Web Services con Haskell en IntelliJ**

La etiqueta [intellij](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij) no aporta nada al problema, si [haskell](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) y [aws](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws)

> Como regla general, se deberían de quitar las etiquetas que no aporten
>   nada al problema.

---

### Los si

**Actualice git y ahora netbeans no reconoce mis los proyectos java que he clonado**

Se puede etiquetar como [netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) sin problemas, ya que entra en la temática del sitio, además que el problema afecta en especifico al IDE en cuestión

**Android studio no me permite hacer debug en mi dispositivo android**

Si bien esta pregunta estaría correctamente etiquetada como [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) usar [android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) no seria incorrecto, ya que algo en la configuración del IDE no permite hacer una de sus características inherentes

**NullPointerException en eclipse**

*Cuando inicio eclipse me tira este error (Captura de pantalla) y se cierra*

Respuesta:

*Ve al archivo /a/b/c/d.config y cambia X por Y*

Mismo título que un ejemplo anterior, pero en este el problema radica en la instalación o configuración del IDE, nada que ver con el lenguaje de programación, siempre etiquetar con el IDE

**STS no me permite desplegar proyectos a tomcat**

Aunque el problema pudiera estar en tomcat, dejar la etiqueta STS refleja que el problema es una combinación de ambos,
dejar (o poner) etiqueta [sts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts)

**Visual Studio 2015 no me permite bajar paquetes de Nuget**

Problema del IDE 100% puede ser algo en la instalación o configuración, puedes etiquetar [visual-studio-2015](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) o
[visual-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) o ambas

**DevC++ Falla al compilar un hola mundo**

*El cuerpo muestra codigo hola mundo perfecto, mas un mensaje que indica que el IDE no encuentra una ruta o tiene algún fallo interno*

Usar etiqueta [devc++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devc%2b%2b) problema de  IDE

**Maven no genera war desde netbeans, pero si desde línea comandos**

Parece fallo de configuración en el IDE, usar [netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans)

**Como identar código PHP en Sublime Text**

Si bien Sublime Text no es un IDE, a veces también se etiquetan mal. Esta pregunta solicita una característica interna dentro de Sublime Text, así que debe ser etiquetada con [sublime-text](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text) y [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

> Como regla general cuando se pregunta por una característica
>   perteneciente al IDE, cuando el IDE no cumple correctamente una
>   función específica que debería realizar